# How to get the list of about-to-be-commited files in JGIT?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, jgit

I need to write a precommit hook for GIT where the about to be commited files are checked to see if they are formatted according to a specific eclipse formatter. For this I need to get the list of the files which are not yet commited and their contents. Can this be done using JGIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, commit hooks aren't yet implemented in JGit. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315

However, for examining the index, you can use the `DirCache` class. DirCache.read(Repository) returns the index for the given repository. You can then either use a `TreeWalk` to iterate over the entries or use getEntryCount() and getEntry().
You may also want to look at the unit tests to get further pointers on how to use the API.